# css linear-gradient background displaying blank in mobile ios safari

Tags: html, css

Background linear gradient is light blue to a darker blue. This displays correctly in desktop ios safari, but in mobile ios safari the gradient is missing makign the background white.

```
    body {
font-family: source-sans-pro;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, right top, from(#2ce9fd), to(#5581ec));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2ce9fd, #5581ec);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2ce9fd, #5581ec);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #2ce9fd, #5581ec);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #2ce9fd, #5581ec); 
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(44, 233, 253,1) 20.5625%,rgba(44, 232, 252,1) 20.5625%,rgba(85, 129, 236,1) 80.5625%);
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 200;}
```

Comment: `background-color` should be `background` and added after all the prefixes one

Comment: @TemaniAfif I applied your suggestions and this did not solve the issue.

Comment: not directly related to your issue but to correct a bad part in your code that may affect other browsers

Comment: Could it be an issue with rgba? Try testing `rgb(44, 233, 253)` and so on for the rest of the values.

Comment: @RickardElimää yes, it did not solve the issue...